# Lollipop isPowerSaveMode always returns false

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to know if the PowerSaveMode is activated or not. I am using this code:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    return pm.isPowerSaveMode();
```

But it always returns FALSE.
I have only tried with a Samsung Galaxy S4 with 5.0.1 because is the only Lollipop device I have around.
Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that Samsung works in a different way.
Like always Android loves to be tricky.

```
bActivated = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "psm_switch").equals("1");
```

I also read that for HTC has to be this way:

```
bActivated = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "user_powersaver_enable").equals("1");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Samsung any more, `psm_switch` always returns 1

Comment: Works perfectly on my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0.1).