# How to check if the Battery Saver Mode is enabled on Android < 5.0?

Tags: android, android-api-levels, power-saving

As I know, there are some devices with version < 5.0 that have the Power Saver option.

An answer provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277525/how-to-check-battery-saver-is-on-in-android-api-21) similar question is not correct and doesn't explain anything.

On Android 5.0+ we can use this script here:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if ( powerManager.isPowerSaveMode()) {
    //code
}
```

My question is: 
is there a universal way to check if there IS a power saver mode and if it's enabled/disabled on API < 21?

Comment: That case, where question is more useful than answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For KitKat and below power saving is not a standard feature enabled in the stock android but some manufacturers implement this through some different methods. So there are no standard ways for checking this.